# Android Print Dialog Options

Tags: android, android-print-framework

I have been trying to preset android print dialog options to user defined settings. But no matter what options i provide to printAttributes, I get only ISO_A4 page size as default in dialog.

Following is the code i have been using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

             int pageTypeValue = Integer.parseInt(mSettingsPreferences.getString(Utility.SETTINGS_PDF_SIZE_TYPE, "4"));

            PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
            String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

            PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
            builder.setMediaSize(getSelectedMediaSize(pageTypeValue));


            printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintAdapter("name_of_file", mFile, FinalPrescriptionActivity.this), builder.build());
```

**where getSelectedMediaSize(int value) returns MediaSize:**

```
public PrintAttributes.MediaSize getSelectedMediaSize(int pageType) {

    switch (pageType) {
        case (0):
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A0;
        case 1:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A1;
        case 2:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A2;
        case 3:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A3;
        case 4:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4;
        case 5:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A5;
        case 6:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A6;
        case 7:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A7;
        case 8:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A8;
        case 9:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER;
        case 10:
            return PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_INDEX_3X5;

        }
    return  null;
    }
```

Can someone please help me to set android print dialog options?

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42796529/1098917).I think your code should work if you test on an N device